# Synchronize Dreamweaver over an SSH tunnel using an SFTP connection

Tags: sync, lan, sftp, dreamweaver, ssh-tunnel

Maybe... Just maybe... I'm asking too much here. Maybe I'm even barking up the wrong tree. I'm looking to essentially have Dreamweaver establish an SSH tunnel to one machine, and then use that connection to synchronize a site that is on another machine entirely.

**Now for some details:**
We've got two connections here at work. We've got our office connection for day to day business, and then we've got some fancy connection hosting our web servers upstairs. For the most part they've been mutually exclusive until recently. We had been establishing an SFTP connection to synchronize our web sites by going out over the office connection to the web and coming back in over the fancy connection to our servers upstairs.

Recently -ish, we [established a LAN connection to one of our servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/178770/setting-up-two-nics-on-two-separate-lans-provides-error) that makes a pleasant change in VNC connection quality. Thanks to Vinagre, this makes it really easy to connect to any of our servers over this LAN connection via SSH tunnel for VNC. However, in spite of that new addition of a LAN connection, we still synchronize over the 'net. Out the office connection and in on the fancy one upstairs. I'm looking to change this.

I'd like to get Dreamweaver to first tunnel over our LAN connection to the servers, and then go from there to whatever connection it needs to. Am I asking too much?

**The current set up:**
Dreamweaver CS4 is installed on Windows XP which is running within VirtualBox on top of Ubuntu 10.10. The network connection for VirtualBox is currently made in NAT mode, but could easily be switched to a Bridged Connection should it need be. The LAN connection is to 1 of 5 servers running CentOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your setup correctly, you put/setup a second NIC in one of your servers on the fancy connection that connects to your office LAN. The dual homed server acts as your high speed gateway to the rest of your servers through ssh tunneling. If all of this is correct I would try the following.

Install putty on your Windows VMs and setup a connection to LAN address of your dual homed server that will forward a port on your VM to port 22 on your destination server. Establish the connection to the dual homed machine and then change your connection profile in Dreamweaver to use localhost as the remote server and change the port from 22 to whatever random number you chose in your putty port forwarding setup(1024-65535). You can forward additional ports to additional servers but you need to pick a unique local/source port for each forwarded connection.

If you want this to be more transparent to the Windows VM there are some things you could do on your Ubuntu box to intercept the ssh traffic and redirect(iptables) it through an ssh tunnel setup in Linux but that just adds additional complexity. Another solution would be to add the rest of your servers to your LAN and reference each of them in Dreamweaver with the local IP/hostname but you will want to think through your security before you go that far.

Comment: I had actually forgotten I had asked this on here. Thank you, chuck!